# Band gap voltammetry sensors

Tags: electrochemistry, materials, cyclic-voltammetry

I'm new in electrochemistry and I am leading with modification of sensors and analytes. I would like to know why the analyte voltammetric signal should be between the band gap of the modifier. If I run a DPV passing through the band gap limit do I lose my electrode? or modification?

Comment: Half of success of obtaining useful answers is providing sufficient relevant context along the questions.